# JavaScript Time Until

Tags: javascript, date

I need to do the simplest thing, take an input date/time and write out the hours:minutes:seconds until that time. I haven't been able to figure it out. I even tried using Datejs which is great, but doesn't seem to have this functionality built in.

The time is going to be somewhere in the range of 0 mins -> 20 minutes

Thanks!

Comment: Try [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). Also, show some code.

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought there might be a library for this... Submit as answer maybe?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't bother with a library for something so simple. You must know the format of the input date string whether you use a library or not, so presuming ISO8601 (like 2013-02-08T08:34:15Z) you can do something like:

```
// Convert string in ISO8601 format to date object
// e.g. 2013-02-08T02:40:00Z
//
function isoToObj(s) {
    var b = s.split(/[-TZ:]/i);

    return new Date(Date.UTC(b[0], --b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5]));

}


function timeToGo(s) {

    // Utility to add leading zero
    function z(n) {
      return (n < 10? '0' : '') + n;
    }

    // Convert string to date object
    var d = isoToObj(s);
    var diff = d - new Date();

    // Allow for previous times
    var sign = diff < 0? '-' : '';
    diff = Math.abs(diff);

    // Get time components
    var hours = diff/3.6e6 | 0;
    var mins  = diff%3.6e6 / 6e4 | 0;
    var secs  = Math.round(diff%6e4 / 1e3);

    // Return formatted string
    return sign + z(hours) + ':' + z(mins) + ':' + z(secs);   
}
```

You may need to play with the function that converts the string to a date, but not much. You should be providing a UTC timestring anyway, unless you can be certain that the local time of the client is set to the timezone of the supplied datetime value.

Comment: You must know the format of the supplied string to use a library anyway, writing your own parser for a particular format is trivial (perhaps 2 or 3 lines of code). Formatting output isn't difficult either, so I don't see the point of a library unless you have other requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Date.js, try [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).